# How to pass clientId and clientSecret values to ET_Client in marketing cloud Fuel SDK in C#?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm getting the following error:

> clientId or clientSecret is null: Must be provided in config file or
>   passed when instantiating ET_Client

although I have added following code before initiating ET_Client as

```
NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
parameters.Add("clientId", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
parameters.Add("clientSecret", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
ET_Client myclient = new ET_Client(parameters);
```

I also have a "FuelSDK_config.xml" with my clientId and clientSecret but not sure Where should I include this xml file and how is it referenced?

Answer (score 0):

The fuelSDK_config.xml goes in the root of your project file. 
You can also have these app settings in your web config:
FuelSDK.appSignature
FuelSDK.clientId
FuelSDK.clientSecret
FuelSDK.soapEndPoint

And then create the ET_Client as new ET_Client(null, true).

See: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp/blob/master/FuelSDK-CSharp/ET_Client.cs line 35 for more details